# Having trouble using Mechanize

Tags: forms, python-2.7, mechanize

So I'm new to using mechanize, and I'm trying to write a program in python 2.7 to log me into my campus wifi.

So I've written some code using mechanize that should log me in. The names of each field are accurate, as is the form name. However, whenever i run the program, nothing seems to happen. it doesn't submit the data, and the program stays running, so i have to force close it.

am i missing anything? i've been hunting over the web, and what i'm doing seems to be okay.

```
mechbrowse=mechanize.Browser()

mechbrowse.open(login_page)

mechbrowse.select_form(name='frmHTTPClientLogin')

mechbrowse.form['username'] = login_username
mechbrowse.form['password'] = login_password

mechbrowse.submit(name='btnSubmit')
```

do i need to write anything so that all this gets executed?

Comment: How far does the code get before it stops?  That may help you find what's wrong.

Comment: it reads the file where it stores the user information, which is right before the steps with mechanize.